# How to display the categories & subcategories in spinner

Tags: android, spinner, categories

[image]

I am new to Android Programming.My need is to find the value for the selected categories in spinners. If an item has sub category, it should display in spinner 2, otherwise not. By selecting the categories, corresponding values should be shown. I need something as in the attached image. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Main Function

```
String[] strings = {"Pilot", "Flight Attendant",
        "Technical"};
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    mySpinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(NewMember.this, R.layout.row, strings));
```

My Adapter Function

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,   String[] objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        label =(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.company);
        label.setText(strings[position]);


        if(label.getText().toString().contains("something"))
        {
           //do anything

        }

        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
If "Pilot" has subcategories, it should display in another spinner. Need to add some values for categories. How to do this ?

Comment: For example Jobs categories, you can change like it : String[] strings = {"Jobs" , "Pilot", "Flight Attendant",
        "Technical"};   and you can add any item to array.

Comment: Thats okay. But when i click Computer Peripheral, something like laptops,desktop etc should be shown in another spinner  and i need to add specific values for each categories.

Comment: Ok. You can create some array for all categories. If you click Computer Peripheral, your array must be equal this category's elements. OK?

Comment: Cant understand.If you give example by writing code, it will be very useful

Comment: You should have two spinner. A spinner is categories and anothet spinner is elements of them. so You should have one array of cetegories and some arrays of elements of categories. Then you should put cetegories array to first spinner for myadapter function. If you click any category, then you should put array of elements of this category to myadapter (2) function and you can do anything.